# Self references several different objects instead of one

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, self, apscheduler

I have a class with a method that creates schedules (it is simplified for the sake of, well, simplicity):

```
def create_schedule(self):
    # Create a function-1 event
    scheduler.add_job(self.function_1,
                      trigger='date',
                      run_date=datetime_1,
                      args=[self])

    # Create a function-2 event
    scheduler.add_job(self.function_2,
                      trigger='date',
                      run_date=datetime_2,
                      args=[self])
```

And these are the class `function_1` and `function_2` methods:

```
def function_1(self, *args):
    print('self in function_1:', self)

def function_2(self, *args):
    print('self in function_2:', self)
```

For some reason, when it executes both events from the scheduler, the following is printed:

```
self in function_1: <program.my_class object at 0x6f03e430>
self in function_2: <program.my_class object at 0x6f03e4b0>
```

i.e. the two are different objects, and thus changes made by `function_1` will not appear in `function_2` and vice-versa.

Why is that? Shouldn't all instances pointed by `self` be the same? Is there a way to circumvent this and force all `self`s to actually point at the same instance?

Comment: Why are you passing in extra `self` arguments? `self.function_1` and `self.function_2` are already bound objects that are guaranteed to pass in `self` again when called.

Comment: How did you configure apscheduler? Are you using a database backend?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: because if I don't pass args=[self] I get an error when the events are scheduled (i.e. 'function_1 is missing one positional argument: self').

Comment: Right, so `apscheduler` unwraps methods. I am not that familiar with how it works, reading up now.

Comment: oh... this can explain it :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You registered two different events with `apscheduler`, which in your configuration stores your event callback information [*in a database in a serialized form*](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#basic-concepts):

> Job stores house the scheduled jobs. The default job store simply keeps the jobs in memory, but others store them in various kinds of databases. **A job’s data is serialized when it is saved to a persistent job store, and deserialized when it’s loaded back from it.**

Bold emphasis mine.

The two jobs you have are executed independently, so they were deserialized independently leading to two new instances being created from the serialized data.

You can't count on separate events to act on the same instance. You'll need to externalize your state, by adding enough identifying information to recreate the state when the job fires.